# Use unshare to start process in existing net namespace?

Tags: bash, namespaces, linux-namespaces

I want to launch a process using isolated namespaces for PID, UTS, IPC, and NET. However, inside the process, to setup the networking correctly, the network namespace has to be configured on the host with the veth adapters (so that they appear for the isolated process). So, I have the network setup using `ip netns add vnet1`. I want to use that network namespace for my process as well as give it PID isolation, etc. I know I can use `ip nets exec` to execute a process in that namespace, but I also want other namespace isolation. Is there a way to do that with `unshare` or do I need to take another approach?

Answer (score 3):

when you run `ip netns add vnet1` it will create an object at `/run/netns` so in this case `/run/netns/vnet1` will be created.

Now, when you `unshare` your program, you can specify path to an existing namespaces. So, maybe like this.

```
$ ip netns add vnet1
$ ls /run/netns/
vnet1
$ unshare --net=/run/netns/vnet1 --pid --uts --ipc --fork bash   
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

You can see that there is only `lo` and no other interfaces meaning that our bash process is now in `vnet1` network namespaces.